# Webview not rendering page on some Windows systems

Tags: go, webview

I am using `github.com/webview/webview` to render a web view on a Go app. It works fine on one system where I am writing it. But the request does not make it to the http server on some clean installed systems. It appears the failure is within the webview dlls. But I am at a loss on how to debug it.

Currently using Go 1.17.1 on Windows 10 Pro x64 21H1

I am running very simple code, similar to the example... I am also using go to serve an http page. I am then opening a webview box to interact with it.

- On the Windows development machine, everything works as expected.
- On a separate clean install of Windows (all same versions), the box comes up blank - just white. Not crashing though. Just not displaying anything.
- Hitting the same URL from a browser on the local machine works. So the page works.
- Changing the URL to refer to an external site (e.g. http://google.com), it works on all machines
- On some machines, it works. Others not.
- I have the DLLs in the same folder as the EXEs.
- Adding debugging statements, it's mostly executing everything as expected.
- However, the request is not making it to the HTTP server
- BTW, the code also works fine on Linux...

The only pattern I can see is that the Windows machines that work seem to be older ones that have existed and been updated for some time. Relatively fresh installs seem to fail. So there must be some kind of subtle dependency?

I'm not sure how to debug this. It seems to be failing within the Webview code.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated... Simple test code below...

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/webview/webview"
)

var (
    IPport = "127.0.0.1:8080"
    URL    = "http://" + IPport
)

func main() {
    log.Print("Starting main")

    go HTTPServer(IPport)

    OpenUI(URL)
}

func OpenUI(url string) {
    log.Print("Starting OpenUI")

    w := webview.New(true)
    defer w.Destroy()

    w.SetTitle("Webview Window")
    w.SetSize(800, 600, webview.HintFixed)
    w.Navigate(url)
    w.Run()
}

func HTTPServer(ipPort string) {
    log.Print("Starting HTTPserver")

    rtr := mux.NewRouter()
    rtr.HandleFunc("/", Page)

    log.Printf("Listening on %s\n", ipPort)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(ipPort, rtr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
}

func Page(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Print("Starting Page handler")

    var err error
    tmpl := template.New("page")

    if tmpl, err = tmpl.ParseFiles("page.gohtml"); err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }

    if err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page", nil); err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }

}
```

page.gohtml

```
{{define "page"}}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Hello Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

Output on working system...

```
2021/09/21 11:51:00 Starting main
2021/09/21 11:51:00 Starting OpenUI
2021/09/21 11:51:00 Starting HTTPserver
2021/09/21 11:51:00 Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
2021/09/21 11:51:02 Starting Page handler
```

Output on failing system... Again, this will work if you hit it with a web browser... e.g. Edge

```
2021/09/21 11:52:00 Starting main
2021/09/21 11:52:00 Starting OpenUI
2021/09/21 11:52:00 Starting HTTPserver
2021/09/21 11:52:00 Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days of fiddling... I figure it out.

You need to actually install one of the Webview2 runtimes. It seems on my older Windows systems, the required dependencies were satisfied through some previous updates or other unknown means. I certainly never installed the runtime specifically. But on a fresh install, you need to install one of the runtime options. You still need the dlls in the same folder as the exe. Once installed, it works everywhere.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution

Someone should update the README to mention the installation of the runtime...  I used the Bootstrapper as it's smaller.

Thanks for listening...